# Setup a scheduled email delivery of Power BI Embedded Report

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, powerbi-embedded

We are setting up embedded reports and one feature clients have asked is the ability to have the reports emailed to them on a scheduled basis.  After researching this it appears that this isn't possible with embedded reports in Power BI but that Power Automate is the recommended way of doing this.

How can I setup a Power Automate flow (or another method) that would allow users to schedule their own report delivery?

I am currently researching this.

I've only found these links that haven't helped me.

[Power BI Embedded Subscription Report email](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Power-BI-embedded-subscription-report-email/m-p/2047247)

[Export and Email a Power BI Report with Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-automate-power-bi-report-export)

Comment: LMK, if the other workaround suits for you or not

Comment: @KotanaSai thank you for the reply.  I have created a power automate flow that will send out an email with a report pdf to either the user that is logged in or from a table I created.  I am unsure how to proceed for automating a scheduled email for a lot of clients.  I'm wondering if this needs to be based off of a table.

I do not believe the 2nd link you sent about utilizing power bi service for subscriptions will work as our reports are embedded.  As it appears this is disabled for embedded reports.

Answer (score 0):

After [Exporting the powerbi embedded report to pdf](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to#usage-examples), you can send out email on schedule basis using the power automate as you mentioned.

The other way you can try out is to subscribe to the report in Power BI Service.
Refer [Email subscriptions for reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/end-user-subscribe?tabs=creator).